# call.data проблемы в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot

this is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQECp.png)

> как сделать что бы внутри цикла принимала последний call.data а не первоначальный главный call.data
>
> how to make sure that the last call.data is received inside the loop and not the initial main call.data

```
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
    def wellll_in_the_aki(call):
        if call.data == 'g11':

          q = aki.start_game(language='ru')

          serts = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)
          item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('иа', callback_data = 'y')
          item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("жоқ", callback_data = 'n')
          item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("idk(білмеймін)", callback_data = 'idk')
          item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("back", callback_data = 'back')


          serts.add(item1, item3, item2, item4)
    
        

         while aki.progression <= 80:

              photo1 = open('staies/maxresdefault.jpg', 'rb')
              photo2 = open('staies/maxresdefault22.jpg', 'rb')

              photochange = [photo1, photo2]

              bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, random.choice(photochange))
              bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, q + "\n\t", reply_markup = serts)
              sleep(5)

              if call.data == "back":
                 try:
                     q = aki.back()
                 except akinator.CantGoBackAnyFurther:
                      pass
              elif call.data == "y":    
                  q = aki.answer("yes")

              elif call.data == "n":
                  q = aki.answer("no")
         
              elif call.data == "idk":
                  q = aki.answer("idk")
              else:
                  bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, call.data)

         aki.win()
    
         bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"Это {aki.first_guess['name']} ({aki.first_guess['description']})! Я прав?\n{aki.first_guess['absolute_picture_path']}\n\t")

         bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id = call.id, show_alert = False, text = "")
```

Comment: Приведите полный трейс ошибки, в нём должно быть написано, на какую именно строку питон ругается. С виду в приведённом коде отступы нормальные.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде смешаны отступы, сделанные с помощью табуляции с отступами, сделанными с помощью пробелов. О чем и говорит перед на русском.
Руководство [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) указывает об использовании четырех пробелов в качестве отступа. Следовательно, чтобы вам решить свою проблему, нужно все отступы сделать в виде четырех пробелов.